# Mysql Error Row xxxx was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()

Tags: mysql

I have query like this:

```
INSERT INTO products_analysis_cache (products_id, group_styles, group_finishing, group_elements, group_materials, group_watchlist)
  SELECT p.products_id,
    CONCAT(',', GROUP_CONCAT(shp.styles_id), ',') AS group_styles,
    group_finishing,
    group_elements,
    group_materials,
    group_watchlist
  FROM products p
    LEFT JOIN styles_has_products shp ON shp.products_id = p.products_id
    LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT pue.products_id, CONCAT(',', GROUP_CONCAT(pue.elements_id),',',IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(paue.elements_id),0), ',') AS group_elements
                FROM products_use_elements pue
                  LEFT JOIN products_articles_use_elements paue ON paue.products_use_elements_id=pue.products_use_elements_id
                GROUP BY pue.products_id
              ) subquery_1 ON subquery_1.products_id = p.products_id
    LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT ptpm.products_id, CONCAT(',', GROUP_CONCAT(ptpm.products_materials_id), ',') AS group_materials
                FROM products_to_products_materials ptpm
                GROUP BY ptpm.products_id
              ) subquery_2 ON subquery_2.products_id = p.products_id
    LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT muwp.products_id, CONCAT(',', GROUP_CONCAT(muwp.user_id), ',') AS group_watchlist
                FROM minierp_users_watch_products muwp
                GROUP BY muwp.products_id
              ) subquery_3 ON subquery_3.products_id = p.products_id
    LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT products_id, fg+fh+fb+fo+fr AS group_finishing FROM
                  (SELECT p.products_id
                     ,IF(SUM(finishing_goldplate)>0,1,0) fg
                     ,IF(SUM(finishing_hammer)>0,11,0) fh
                     ,IF(SUM(finishing_brush)>0,111,0) fb
                     ,IF(SUM(finishing_oxid)>0,1111,0) fo
                     ,IF(SUM(finishing_rosegoldplate)>0,11111,0) fr
                   FROM products p
                     INNER JOIN products_use_elements pue ON pue.products_id = p.products_id
                   GROUP BY pue.products_id
                  ) dt
              ) subquery_4 ON subquery_4.products_id = p.products_id
  GROUP BY p.products_id ORDER BY p.products_id DESC;
```

But when i ran it. Mysql throws error

```
[HY000][1260] Row 8036 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()
```

This is the table that i wanted to insert.

```
CREATE TABLE `products_analysis_cache` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `group_styles` longtext NOT NULL,
  `group_finishing` longtext NOT NULL,
  `group_elements` longtext NOT NULL,
  `group_materials` longtext NOT NULL,
  `group_watchlist` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`),
  KEY `idx_products_id` (`products_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I already make LONGTEXT for each column to accepted a long text, but still got the same error.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks for the help.
EDIT:
I've set group_concat_max_len to the max value available (18446744073709551615) according to mysql documentation, and it still shows error 'was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()'

Answer (score 4):

Try increasing the value of `group_concat_max_len` as explained [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len). This is what it says:

> The maximum permitted result length in bytes for the GROUP_CONCAT()
>   function. The default is 1024.

Comment: @Erick what length have you set it to?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) variable to bigger value. Or perhaps use [`GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to shorthen the result.

Comment: Hi, it still show the same error even if i set it to the max value for group_concat_max_len